# From WSL, how can I determine if a file is hidden, according to Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Python 3.5 on the Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04. When finding files, such as using os.walk, I want to filter out hidden files (and directories) such as "desktop.ini" and  "Thumbs.db". But they look like regular files from Ubuntu.

Because I'm running Ubuntu, ctypes.windll doesn't load so those solutions aren't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the output with something like sed or awk but the command `cmd.exe /c dir /S /A:H` will do what you are after.

Display all files with the hidden attribute `/A:H` in the current directory and recursively `/S` below it.

EDIT

the following is the output when i run the command from inside my windows user directory

```
➜  cd /mnt/c/Users/damo
➜  cmd.exe /c dir /A:H
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is B8E3-7234

 Directory of C:\Users\damo

25/11/2019  10:04    <DIR>          AppData
20/02/2020  08:16    <DIR>          IntelGraphicsProfiles
25/11/2019  15:42    <DIR>          MicrosoftEdgeBackups
17/02/2020  10:04         7,864,320 NTUSER.DAT
25/11/2019  10:04           696,320 ntuser.dat.LOG1
20/02/2020  08:16         1,048,576 NTUSER.DAT{c17b7660-0d10-11ea-a41b-88b111e240a6}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
25/11/2019  10:50           524,288 NTUSER.DAT{c17b7661-0d10-11ea-a41b-88b111e240a6}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
25/11/2019  10:50           524,288 NTUSER.DAT{c17b7661-0d10-11ea-a41b-88b111e240a6}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
25/11/2019  10:04                20 ntuser.ini
17/02/2020  10:08            21,126 ntuser.pol
              12 File(s)     13,824,666 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  325,835,501,568 bytes free
➜
```

Notice in this example i did not include the /S and i ran this from directly inside WSL.

Could you also check the version of CMD that you are using form WSL by issuing the following `which cmd.exe` which for me returns `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`

Comment: I tried a few variations of "dir" and it won't accept any of the / attributes. I'm guessing because it thinks that it's a path. I tried with and without cmd.exe. With it, I never got a response. I learned that cmd.exe was recognized by WSL, which was a surprise to me.

Comment: Ive added a little clarification to my answer, do you get any response from the command? can you see the dir and files when using it?

Comment: Also try `cmd.exe /c "dir /?"` to get help on the dir command, does this work. You could also try wrapping the command in double quotes like ive shown here, maybe your shell is interfearing with the command sent to cmd.exe Try this `cmd.exe /c "dir /S /A:H"`

Comment: I'm at a loss for why I wasn't seeing anything when I used "cmd", but using your new example works. Because I wasn't seeing a response from "cmd", I had skipped using it once I found that "dir" worked. I guess "dir" is an alias for "ls" or something similar.

Your approach seems to work as long as paths are added Windows-style (backslash). I'm not sure I can use it as a solution because I'm drilling down directories, and getting responses may be too slow. I'll have to do some timing tests -- another unplanned task! Thanks for clarifying. Damo.

Comment: Try combining with wslpath to use in a named directory `cmd.exe /c dir /A:H "$(wslpath -w /mnt/c/program\ files/)"`